# Finding context menu of Elevation Surfaces in Contents pane of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

[image]

I have recently installed ArcGIS Pro and can't find the Elevation Surface tab (which should be in properties of 3D Map in the Contents as it is shown in the tutorials).

Could anyone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: What tutorial are you referring to?  What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?  Do you have the 3D Analyst extension licensed?

Comment: I have AcrGIS Pro version 10.6.1. According to the tutorial (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/properties/elevation-surfaces.htm) : "You can optionally use the context menu for the Elevation Surfaces group in the Contents pane to add a new custom surface and configure its source" however I don't see this menu in the Contents pane. 3D Analyst is activated.

Comment: I think you are confusing ArcMap/ArcScene and ArcGIS Pro. If you included a picture of your menu/toolbar it would be easier to tell which.

Comment: How can I include the picture now? I am just trying to exaggerate the high of my DEM however without elevation surface tab I cannot do it..

Comment: Use the [edit] button beneath your question to start editing and then use the Picture button to include a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the picture above accordingly. As it is seen there is not any Elevation Surface tab in the properties..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have right-clicked on Scene and opened its Properties.

To see the context menu of the Elevation Surfaces *group* (not tab) try right-clicking on the Elevation Surface group which in your picture is the fourth to bottom item in the Contents pane.